# Bash Checking Specifically Formatted User Input

Tags: bash, input, format, range, error-checking

I am trying to implement a check in my script to make sure that the user is entering the data in the correct format.

1. I need a check that will ensure that users are inputting a positive whole number directly followed by the letter 'k'

   **Examples of valid input:**
   4k
   25k
   17k
   **Examples of invalid input**
   2.1
   4j
   -2k
   **What I need**
   if [[ input is in correct format ]]; then
   ...
   ...
   fi

**EDIT:**
So far what I have for this is the following:
if ! [[ regex =~ ^[1-9]+k$ ]]; do
but this does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

2. This one is a little trickier. I need a check that will ensure that users are entering a range of values denoted by the minimum and maximum ranges directly followed by a 'k' and separated by a dash with no spaces. They can also enter multiple ranges which would be separated by commas with no spaces.

   **Examples of valid input:**
   4k-5k
   1k-2k
   3k-6k,1k-9k,3k-8k
   2k-5k,12k-20k
   **Examples of invalid input**
   2.5-3 4k-10k
   4k-3k, 8k-9k
   7k - 9k, -3-6
   **What I need**
   if [[ input is in correct format ]]; then
   ...
   ...
   fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty reasonable to do using [regular expressions in BASH](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns). Additional details are available in [the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

```
singleinputregex='^[1-9][0-9]*k$'
if [[ $singleinput =~ $singleinputregex ]]; then
  # ...
fi

rangeinputregex='^[1-9][0-9]*k-[1-9][0-9]*k(,[1-9][0-9]*k-[1-9][0-9]*k)*$'
if [[ $rangeinput =~ $rangeinputregex ]]; then
  # ...
fi
```

Comment: This is not working. Still need a solution. I think you are close tho

Comment: Typos fixed, but without some idea of exactly what is "still not working", it'll be harder to debug further. In any case, StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service; hopefully this answer gets you close enough to write a proper solution. :)

Comment: Well I see you are using the *  symbol. That won't work because it matches 0 or more of the preceding character. I need the user to enter at least 1 digit, so the + operator is what I need instead of the *.
Now I have 

if ! [[ regex =~ ^[1-9][0-9]+k$ ]]; then

And this doesnt seem to be working. I cant get it to pass no matter what input I use.

I really appreciate your help thus far

Comment: `*` is intentional and important. `[1-9][0-9]*` matches a nonzero digit followed by zero-or-more other digits. If zero is allowed, you could do `[0-9]+`, but your combination `[1-9][0-9]+k` will only match two-digit numbers or longer.

Comment: ahh interesting. you're right. this is why i come here :)